# Meaning of return 2 statement in c++ programming language

Tags: c++

I am having a code in which there is return 2 at some places and I am not able to understand its meaning. Anyone can help me to explain this return 2 meaning. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can we understand code that you do not show us?  We cannot see your monitor from here.

Comment: [If it helps...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Comment: The answer depends on what the function that contains this code is supposed to do. Read the function's documentation -- that should explain what various return values mean.

Comment: Seems like a Bad alloc in the case you show.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
return 2;
```

means the function, in which it is, returns value `2`.

The caller function may use that value as an indication of the callee function termination condition (in the excerpt given it possibly is a specific value with the hidden meaning assigned 'could not create new CATDocumentServices' or simply 'something went wrong'...).

Answer (score 0):

In C++ the `return` statement returns from the current function as in

```
void func(arg_type arg)
{
  // some code
  return;  // can appear almost anywhere in the function body, including several times
  // more code 
}
```

Functions requiring a return value require such a value to be given in the `return` statement as in

```
return_value_type func(arg_type arg)
{
  // ...
  return some_value_of_return_value_type;
  // ...
}
```

In your case, it appears that the statements are taken from the body of a function returning an `int` (or a related type convertible from `int`). So, `return 2` simply returns the value 2. Thus, if you have

```
int my_func()
{
  // ...
  CATDocument* pDoc = NULL;
  auto hr = CATDocumentServices::New("CATDrawing", pDoc);
  if (FAILED(hr)) return 2;
  // ...
}

int val = my_func();
```

will assign 2 to val in case the path of execution taken went over the `return 2` statement in `my_func()`.

Comment: u mean if this function executes till return statement then value 2 will be saved in val finally...did I get this right as you said

Comment: I edited the questions to make it clearer.